# Shortcodes and javascript inclusion

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I’m experiencing an issue where shortcode is only echoed and not executed i.e. here is what I actually see on my web page:

> ［ajax_filter_posts per_page="10"］

Here is my function.php file http://termbin.com/v6v5

```
//enqueue and localizing the Javascript.

function assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax_filter_post_mdu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', ['jquery'], null, true);
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_filter_post_mdu', 'bobz', array(
        'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'bobz' ),
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'assets', 100);
```

Here is how I’m calling the shortcode in my personal category-template.php http://termbin.com/8r3x

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('［ajax_filter_posts per_page="10"］'); ?>
```

From what I understand I’m doing something wrong, maybe around the enqueue and or localization but I don’t understand where's the mistake. Also, the javascript properly loads as the browser doesn't complain about the file not found.

Also in my template category.php file i call the function directly like this for instance:

```
<?php   $a = array('post_tag', false, false);
        $pub_tag = vb_filter_posts_sc( $a );
        echo $pub_tag;
?>
```

It does work properly…

I’ve forked 2016 Wordpress built-in theme and hack from here, am I having a conflict somewhere?

I have searched as much as I could but can't get it sorted out.

Comment: can i see the code where you used the shortcode, may be in your template file?

Comment: Can you post the essential parts of your code in the question

Comment: I have edited my post with the proper link for category template file.

Comment: @Panda the thing is i'm not sure if it's only my code which is the problem or a potential conflict with the other part of the codes, that's why i took the part to post everything. But here is the strip down i can give 

Enqueue and localize http://pastebin.com/xRD0Janv

Comment: @MatthieuDucorps Yea, it's better to post it directly in the question

Comment: and 

Shortcode usage in template category http://pastebin.com/UyN6XFbF

Comment: your braces don't look right ... `<?php echo do_shortcode('［ajax_filter_posts per_page="10"］'); ?>` maybe try this? `<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_filter_posts per_page="10"]'); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post the code where your shortcode is defined.

It would look something like `add_shortcode('ajax_filter_post', ...)`. You didn't state if you're providing the shortcode or if it's in some plugin that you're not responsible for.

You can see what shortcodes are defined as follows:

```
global $shortcode_tags;
print_r($shortcode_tags);
```

That will (should) give you an array with all the defined shortcodes. If `ajax_filter_post` does not appear on that list, your shortcode isn't defined.

Depending on where this content lies, you may have a problem with the order of filters. That is, whatever is expanding this shortcode may run after `wp_enqueue_scripts` already ran. If this happens your JS code will never make it to the browser. The work-around for that would be to enqueue the JS on every page and only use it when something with your shortcode comes up. For instance, the shortcode could output this HTML:

```
<div class="my-shortcode-target"></div>
```

And jQuery something like this:

```
jQuery(() => { (($) => {
    $('.my-shortcode-target').each(() => {
        var $target = $(this);
        $.ajax({'url': bobz.ajax_url, 'data': { 'nonce': bobz.nonce } }).done((data) => {
            // Here's where you can do stuff using what was returned from your AJAX call.
            target.append($('<span>').text(data.answer));
        });
    });
})(jQuery); });
```

Your shortcode seems to be filtering something, so you'd replace the DOM manipulation in there with the thing that decides what to show and what not to show.

Comment: Perfect answer! Now i got it didn't "add_shortcode"!